# How to make custom follow cursor follow Y axis scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a bit of HTML & CSS on my squarespace site to create a custom follow cursor. I want to just have a floaty circle with no actual cursor displayed. I've gotten it to mostly work, but when my site scrolls the follow cursor doesn't move with the page scroll and just gets stuck at the top.

And that just caused the follow cursor to stop moving with mouse movement entirely, becoming static on the center of the page.

Injecting HTML & CSS on to squarespace site to create a custom follow cursor:

```css
body {
     background: #161616;
}

.wrap {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#ball {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     background: none;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="followMouse();">
     <div class="wrap">
          <div id="ball"></div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">

         var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
         var $on = document.addEventListener.bind(document);
         var xmouse, ymouse;

         $on('mousemove', function (e) {
             xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
             ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
         });

         var ball = $('#ball');
         var x = void 0,
             y = void 0,
             dx = void 0,
             dy = void 0,
             tx = 0,
             ty = 0,
             key = -1;
      
         var followMouse = function followMouse() {
             key = requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

             if(!x || !y) {
                 x = xmouse;
                 y = ymouse;
             } else {
                 dx = (xmouse - x) * 0.125;
                 dy = (ymouse - y) * 0.125;

                 if(Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy) < 0.1) {
                      x = xmouse;
                      y = ymouse;
                 } else {
                      x += dx;
                      y += dy;
                 }
             }
          
             ball.style.left = x + 'px';
             ball.style.top = y + 'px';
         };

     </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Great job on updating your question, the demo and the problem are very clear now.  Don't worry about your demo not scrolling, I just added a bunch of divs with some height in my demo to simulate that.  Here's everything you need to / should change to make it all work:

1. `var followMouse = function followMouse() ...` is very strange syntax and I'm not sure what the exact outcome will be.

   - Either declare the function normally `function followMouse() ...`, or store it in a variable using either the:

     - function definition `var followMouse = function() ...` or
     - arrow definition `var followMouse = () => ...`
2. To simply get it all working you just need to adjust for the current scroll amount of either the document or in my demo's case the element with class ".wrap".

   - This can be done using the `scrollTop` member of the object returned by your `$()` function.
   - I started by just adding `$(".wrap").scrollTop` to the `ymouse` variable in the `mousemove` listener, but while this works it needs you to move the mouse for the circle to realize it's scrolled off the page.
   - So instead we just add `$(".wrap").scrollTop` to the css that is being set to the ball in the last lines of `followMouse`.
3. I changed the `overflow` property from `hidden` to `scroll` since that's kind of where the problem is occuring ;)
4. I've also added `cursor: none` to your `.wrap` css so that you get the desired effect of no cursor but your custom one.

```js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var $on = document.addEventListener.bind(document);
var followMouse = function() {
  key = requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

  if (!x || !y) {
    x = xmouse;
    y = ymouse;
  } else {
    dx = (xmouse - x) * 0.125;
    dy = (ymouse - y) * 0.125;
    if (Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy) < 0.1) {
      x = xmouse;
      y = ymouse;
    } else {
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
    }
  }
  ball.style.left = x + 'px';
  ball.style.top = $(".wrap").scrollTop + y + 'px';
};

var xmouse, ymouse;
var ball = $('#ball');
var x = void 0,
  y = void 0,
  dx = void 0,
  dy = void 0,
  tx = 0,
  ty = 0,
  key = -1;

$on('mousemove', function(e) {
  xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
  ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  cursor: none;
}

#ball {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.makeOverflow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="followMouse();">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="ball"></div>
    <div class="makeOverflow"> </div>
    <div class="makeOverflow"> </div>
    <div class="makeOverflow"> </div>
    <div class="makeOverflow"> </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I updated that formatting, thank you and sorry about that! Let me know if I've forgotten anything. Edit: Looks like the demo is running properly now, but I'm not sure how to demonstrate that scrolling up and down a page causes the follow circle to get stuck.

Comment: Stack Overflow was not built for the kind of back-and-forth conversation you detail in your answer. If you want that type of conversation, use [chat] and bring the end result here. Otherwise, what chance do other answers have?

Comment: My bad, not trying to steal anyone's chance at answering but in my time on SO I often see questions going unanswered forever due to users choosing to solely discuss in the comments or because they're not happy with the format of the question.  By answering I both expressed interest in answering for the OP while also giving the feedback he needed.   Plus answering allowed me to use a snipped which neither the comments nor a chat could do, but I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Very elegant way to simulate jQuery, is not linked to the original question but from your answer coding style. Have you any link to prupose for learning some additional trick to simulate jQuery syntax ? Thanks again for your clean solution

Comment: Happy to help @Yanis-git !  Unfortunately I can't take credit for the jQuery trick as it was included in the original question, but I do agree it's quite impressive and I've never seen this trick before.  As for tutorials I have no idea, I've done a little bit of trickery to emulate jQuery in the past (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatthewDLudwig/011ebf39a3956ed404b41d8d10c4e693/raw/de0c3bcb9a4afaf76459e6d29300240cd201e3f9/jquery.js) but it was very hacky, personally I use Vue.js or other MVC frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I just tried implementing this new version on the site and it's still resulting in the same problem, but at this point I have to assume it's a squarespace issue preventing the code injection from working properly. Oddly, the circle itself still shows up and tracks the cursor appropriately, but scrolling still leaves the circle hanging at the top of the page and cursor: none in the CSS doesn't work. Regardless, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hopefully you come back to check this comment as I love solving these kinds of issues.  Could you put a link to the squarespace in the comments?  If I had to guess your issue is that squarespace is wrapping around everything and we're simply not looking at the `scrollTop` value of the correct element.  A few minutes with your site and I may be able to figure out which is the correct element to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be fixed by changing the #ball CSS from being absolutely positioned to a fixed position, then it should scroll down the page with your original js